# id order is mixed while using order by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I am using MySQL as a database.

Now I got everything working correctly but as my client wants to have filter on the website I am in the some sort of problem of what exactly I need to do and what would be the best way of doing it.

So this is my data ( I will simplify it as much as possible )

```
id  name  price  nr.bed  nr.bath
---------------------------------
1     a     33     2        4
2     b    100     5        1
3     c    102     2        2 
4     d     85     1        1
5     e     37     6        4 
6     f     19     2        1
```

So first time page loads I am using this query to get first 5 from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel LIMIT 5
```

And I get this:

```
id  name  price  nr.bed  nr.bath
---------------------------------
1     a     33     2        4
2     b    100     5        1
3     c    102     2        2 
4     d     85     1        1
5     e     37     6        4
```

After that each time I am calling this:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id>'last_id(in this case 5)' LIMIT 5
```

And I am getting:

```
id  name  price  nr.bed  nr.bath
--------------------------------- 
6     f     19     2        1
```

And so on...

But now I need to use filter for example I will have filter for price

So I need to have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel where id>5 order by price desc LIMIT 5
```

But then I am loosing my id order and I can't get next five from the database because I can't compare to and `id` of hotel because everything is orderd by price.

How can I achieve this?
Do I need to add another column or something which will keep my order as it is? Everything is presented on the website using and id from the table.

EDIT:

I am not sure if that is even possible because I need to have id ordered in asc and price in desc but I am not sure if we can combine those two together without adding another column or something.

EDIT2:

I would like to get something like this

```
id  id_copy  name  price  nr.bed  nr.bath
-----------------------------------------
 1      3     c     102     2        2 
 2      2     b     100     5        1
 3      4     d      85     1        1
 4      5     e      37     6        4 
 5      1     a      33     2        4
 6      6     f      19     2        1
```

Comment: how are you generating the 2nd query?

Comment: how is `SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id>'last_id(in this case 5)' LIMIT 5` created?

Comment: how about sending the `id` on `order by`?

Comment: I am getting the last id from the previous query... from JSON data and then I am passing it in sql with php

Comment: what result you want get ?

Comment: can you show the result you want get in your question ?

Comment: *"...I need to have id ordered in asc and price in desc..." That's not possible, except by sheer coincidence. If you have the tuples {1, $1.00}, {2, $2.00}, would you really want the query output to show {1, $2.00}, {2, $1.00}? Of course not.

Comment: your result means that u dont select id > 5 ?

Comment: Are you using `id` as a cheap way to keep things in the order that they were inserted into the table?  If so, stop that.  Add a proper date_added timestamp column and use that.  IDs should only be used to identify the record, and nothing else.  It is unobvious to the next person reading your code why you are placing significance on the numeric value of an ID.  Also, if you want to change the insertion time of a record after the fact, so that it looks like it was added earlier or later, you're out of luck because you can't change the ID.  **Only use IDs for identifying, not sequencing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should never use `limit` without `order by` when the ordering is important.  Your queries should be like:

```
SELECT *
FROM hotel
WHERE id>'last_id(in this case 5)'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5
```

For your question, you want a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT * FROM hotel where id>5 order by price desc LIMIT 5
     ) t
order by id
```

The inner query selects the 5 by price.  The outer one orders by id.

If you want to use this for "pagination", then you should become familiar with the `offset` argument to `limit`.  This is described in the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: @denonth . . . Why would you call with `id>6`.  You would have the same query, replacing the `limit 5` with `limit 5, 5` and then `limit 10, 5`.  Your attempts to use the id for paging are misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Order two columns then:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel where id>5 order by price desc , id asc LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @denonth - In that case - what is the output you are expecting to occur?

Answer (score 0):

i think this what you are looking for

```
   SELECT * FROM hotel  order by price desc limit 0 ,5
```

then if you want next 5

```
 SELECT * FROM hotel  order by price desc limit 5 ,5
```

then

```
   SELECT * FROM hotel  order by price desc limit 10 ,5
```

and so on...

you can make this in php like that

```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM hotel  order by price desc "

if (sombutton is clicked) {
          $sql .= " limit 0,5" ;}
 if (sombutton is clicked){ 
                       $sql .= " limit 5,5" ; }
```

or you can do it by a loop with variable `$i` everytime you add 5.